# if mouseout of one element == true && mouseover of the other element != true

Tags: javascript, html

If the dom contains the following nodes:

```
<span id="one_element"></span> 
<div id="the_other_element"></div>
```

how to call some function in the event when the mouse cursor is out of the one element but not over the other element? Is there a method?

(the one element may be either block-level or inline-level, positioned static, relative, or absolute; the other element is positioned absolute in relation to the document and may overlay the one element.)

Comment: are you using any javascript library? (jquery? prototype? extjs?)

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using any JS Library you could use global state variables like this:

```
<script>
var theOtherElementCursor = false;

function myEvent() {
    if (!theOtherElementCursor) {
        // Do something here!
    }
}
</script>
.
.
.
<span id="one_element" onMouseOut="myEvent()"></span> 
<div id="the_other_element" 
     onMouseOver="theOtherElementCursor = true;"
     onMouseOut="theOtherElementCursor = false;"></div>
```

Comment: I've not tested but will the mouseover of one_element definitely be fired before the mouseout of the_other_element?

Comment: If DIVs / SPANs are overlapped maybe things can go wrong. You should test it in several different scenarios, or put your code.